# How to implement searchbar if the tableview is loaded from a dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a table view and adding items to that like this.`

```
 NSDictionary *memberInfo = [self.currentChannel infoForMemberWithID:memberID];

    memberinfo=memberInfo;

  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[memberinfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[memberinfo objectForKey:@"status"]];


    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

  return cell;
```

`and it was working fine.Now i want to add a searchbar on to that.i need to load the tableview according to the matched string.But i am loading the tableview like this.I know how to search in an array.I am using

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText.i want to load the table view according to the match of the searchstring ,Can anybody know this?
```

Comment: how many rows do u have here.. how r u maintaining that.?

Comment: @vishy means?i have members count as row numbers

Comment: means you have n number of objects in dict, and n number of rows..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate inside your SearchBar delegate to filter your main array (members or whatever you named it) and catch the results in an another global declared array. Now reload your table with this filtered array.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [_mArrFilteredList removeAllObjects]; //global array which will contain filtered results
    NSString* searchStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*",_srbActivity.text];

    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",@"name", searchStr];  //will filter according to "name" key in your dictionary.
    [_mArrFilteredList addObjectsFromArray:[_mArrList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]]; //_mArrList is your main array which has all the dictionaries.
    [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Now in your tableview datasource methods, populate table using filtered array(_mArrFilteredList).

Answer (score 0):

For any search implementations we require two lists, one original and other filtered. We will usually use filtered list to fill up the table.

In your case, you can have dictionary as original list. For filtered list you can have a `NSArray` of values or keys according to requirements.

Filter the array list in search function, reload the table. In `cellForRow` get the object from the array keys or get key from array values- later object for that key.